# Designing a table view cell in iOS for providing two possible ways to enter data

Tags: forms, tables, ios, human-interface-guideline

I have a table view in an iOS app that is a form for requesting user data. One of the fields (a cell in the table view) is intended for requesting a serial number the user could enter either by typing it, or by taking a picture (then, the app should recognize it). I'd want to show the serial number in the cell once provided, something like this (not necessarily a blue details label):

[image: iPhone form]

How can I show in this cell that there are two exclusive options for entering the requested data? Maybe placing some kind of button inside, then showing an action sheet, then displaying the camera view if the "take picture" option is selected, and enabling a text field in the cell itself if "enter manually" is selected? If placing a button inside the cell is a good approach, what kind of icon should be appropiate and where could I place it inside the cell? Since I already need to display the serial number value...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Will mentioned, putting a camera icon on the input field is a good option.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faj2PG.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Alternatively, you can use the standard iOS keyboard camera icon when the user selects the serial input field.

[image: iOS keyboard camera icon]

Answer (score 2):

Putting the camera icon within the editable text-box along with suggestive text "Serial Number" will make it fairly evident that the user can type or click the icon to meet the same need.  See the chat interface in both Facebook and Message iPhone apps for something similar.

Comment: I see... this could be a nice option, thanks. However, I'm thinking about also placing some kind of icon after validation to show if the value entered is valid or not... I think I won't have space enough for the name of the field, a camera button, a text field and a validation icon... any ideas?